# Is it possible to insert a navigation symbol before the standard navigation bar in beamer?

Tags: beamer, navigation

I don't want to remove the navigation bar, I just want to insert a new symbol before it. I'm using the following snippet to add the frame number of the total frames in the navigation bar, but it is rendered in the bottom right and I wanted to be centered with the frame.

```
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1mm}
    \insertframenumber\ of\ \inserttotalframenumber
}
```

Comment: Please don't post just code fragments, always make a small, but compilable test document so that people willing to help you don't have to first spend time adding all the missing pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually add some space to move the navigation symbols towards the centre:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{
    symbol before
}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1mm}
    \insertframenumber\ of\ \inserttotalframenumber
    \hspace{3.4cm}
}

\begin{document}

\section{title 1}    
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the default theme ... (please post always a minimal working example with all that must be taken into account), you can add the navigations symbols and whatever as a  centered  footline:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\color{structure}
\centering {\large$\Phi$}\qquad
\insertslidenavigationsymbol%
\insertframenavigationsymbol%
\insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol%
\insertsectionnavigationsymbol%
\insertdocnavigationsymbol%
\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol%
\qquad\insertframenumber\ of\ \inserttotalframenumber\medskip\par}

\begin{document}
\section{title 1}    
\begin{frame}{Test}{test}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```